# average centrality networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a directed graph G with nodes and edges(weighted) and Im calculating in_degree_centrality(G) and out_degree_centrality(G) for every node and when I average each of them individually I dont know why but for all the graphs the avg indegree is the same as the avg outdegree. I think there is something wrong with add_edge. In my graph there could be more than 1 edge between the same 2 nodes and its weight is the ocurrance of that edge in the csv edge file.

```
for path in files:

dirname, filename = os.path.split(path)   
with open ('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/nodos/%s' %filename) as csvfile,open ('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/aristasPeso/%s' %filename) as csvfile2,open('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/resultados/%s' %filename,'w') as output,open('C:/Users/Sebastian/Desktop/vectores/aristas.csv','a') as output3:       
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    cont=0
    G=nx.DiGraph()
    for row in csv_reader:
        new_node = row[1]                
        new_attributes = row[:1]
        G.add_node(new_node, my_attributes=new_attributes)     
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile2, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        source=row[0]
        target=row[1]
        peso=row[2]           
        #if int(peso)>1:
        G.add_edge(source,target,weight=int(peso))
        cont=cont+1


    #centrality
    cercania=nx.closeness_centrality(G,normalized=True)
    bet_cen = nx.betweenness_centrality(G,normalized=True)
    eig_cen = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G,max_iter=100)
    centralidad_grado=nx.degree_centrality(G)
    indegree = nx.in_degree_centrality(G)
    out = nx.out_degree_centrality(G)
    pr = nx.pagerank(G,alpha=0.85)


    #calculo promedio de metricas en G
    avg_cer=round((sum(cercania.values())/len(cercania)),4)
    avg_bet=round((sum(bet_cen.values())/len(bet_cen)),4)
    avg_eig=round((sum(eig_cen.values())/len(eig_cen)),4)
    avg_cent=round((sum(centralidad_grado.values())/len(centralidad_grado)),4)
    avg_pr=round((sum(pr.values())/len(pr)),4)
    avg_in=round((sum(indegree.values())/len(indegree)),4)
    avg_out=round((sum(out.values())/len(out)),4)

    #convert to undirected
    G_ud = G.to_undirected()
    cluster=nx.average_clustering(G_ud)
    cluster_redondeado=round(cluster,4)


    #resultados metricas de todos los autores en 1 solo archivo csv
    #busco id de autores
    search(autores,filename)
    id=search(autores,filename)
    output3.write(str(avg_cer)+';'+str(avg_bet)+';'+str(avg_eig)+';'+str(cluster_redondeado)+';'+str(avg_cent)+';'+str(avg_pr)+';'+str(avg_in)+';'+str(avg_out)+';'+str(id)+'\n')
```

output for first 4 graphs

```
                                               indeg    outdeg  
0.5253  0.0327  0.1044  0.7251  0.5302  0.0312  0.2651  0.2651  1
0.5342  0.0304  0.102   0.7745  0.536   0.0303  0.268   0.268   1
0.5134  0.0378  0.12    0.6598  0.4778  0.0345  0.2389  0.2389  1
0.5657  0.0302  0.1128  0.6739  0.6527  0.0345  0.3264  0.3264  1
```

my nodes format(word,postag) csv file:

```
What, WP
makes, VBZ
them, PRP
do, VB
it, PRP
Abject, NNP
need, NN
```

edges format(source,target,weight) csv file:

```
 WP, VBZ,2
 VBZ, PRP,2
 PRP, VB,3
 VB, PRP,3
 PRP, NNP,1
 NNP, NN,8
```

But if I print the indegree and outdegree values they are not equal (first graph)

```
{' WP': 0.1935483870967742, ' VBZ': 0.29032258064516125, ' PRP': 
 0.45161290322580644, ' VB': 0.22580645161290322, ' NNP': 
 0.45161290322580644, ' NN': 0.5161290322580645, ' CC': 0.1935483870967742, 
' IN': 0.6129032258064516, ' DT': 0.6129032258064516, ' JJ': 
 0.5806451612903225, ' TO': 0.45161290322580644, ' RB': 0.5806451612903225, 
' WRB': 0.12903225806451613, ' NNS': 0.5483870967741935, ' VBN': 
0.3548387096774194, ' WDT': 0.1935483870967742, ' VBP': 0.16129032258064516, 
' PRP$': 0.3225806451612903, ' MD': 0.22580645161290322, ' EX': 
0.06451612903225806, ' CD': 0.25806451612903225, ' POS': 0.0967741935483871, 
' WP$': 0.06451612903225806, ' VBG': 0.3225806451612903, ' VBD': 
 0.29032258064516125, ' RBR': 0.0967741935483871, '000': 
0.03225806451612903, ' RBS': 0.03225806451612903, ' RP': 
0.03225806451612903, ' FW': 0.03225806451612903, ' JJS': 
0.03225806451612903, ' JJR': 0.03225806451612903}

{' WP': 0.22580645161290322, ' VBZ': 0.29032258064516125, ' PRP': 
0.4193548387096774, ' VB': 0.3870967741935484, ' NNP': 0.7096774193548387, ' 
NN': 0.7741935483870968, ' CC': 0.3870967741935484, ' IN': 
0.5161290322580645, ' DT': 0.3225806451612903, ' JJ': 0.4838709677419355, ' 
TO': 0.1935483870967742, ' RB': 0.4838709677419355, ' WRB': 
0.0967741935483871, ' NNS': 0.5806451612903225, ' VBN': 0.3225806451612903, 
' WDT': 0.12903225806451613, ' VBP': 0.25806451612903225, ' PRP$': 
0.12903225806451613, ' MD': 0.12903225806451613, ' EX': 0.06451612903225806, 
' CD': 0.25806451612903225, ' POS': 0.1935483870967742, ' WP$': 
0.06451612903225806, ' VBG': 0.3870967741935484, ' VBD': 0.3548387096774194, 
' RBR': 0.0967741935483871, '000': 0.06451612903225806, ' RBS': 
0.03225806451612903, ' RP': 0.03225806451612903, ' FW': 0.03225806451612903, 
' JJS': 0.03225806451612903, ' JJR': 0.03225806451612903}
```

Comment: There may be a translation issue, but I think you're saying that for a given graph, the average indegree and the average outdegree are the same.  Why does that surprise you?

Comment: but every node in my graph supose to have different in and out edges , its directed graph :/

Comment: Do a couple small examples by hand.  While you're doing it, check if you can find any relationship between the average in and out-degrees and the number of edges.

Comment: What Joel is trying to teach you is that the average in-degree and out-degree should be the same for any graph. You would have us worried if they were not. If you follow Joel 's excellent suggestion, you will find that the both, the average in-degree and the average out-degree only depend on the total number of nodes and the total number of edges. For the same graph, those two remain constant and hence the mean of the two measures is the same as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I will proces it :D